# Linux difference between root shell "#" and "sh-4.2 #"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the difference between running a root shell and a "sh-4.2#"  in linux?
I am actually trying out buffer overflow attacks to start a root shell. When I use the "bin/zsh"  and perform the attack, I am able to get the root shall with a "#" prompt. But when use the /bin/bash, I am get a shell with a "sh-4.2#" prompt. Just wanted to know the difference.

Comment: I do not have any idea what you're asking.

Comment: I am assuming this has something to do with the prompt and nothing else.

Comment: Are you talking about the kvm shell?

Comment: http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_tip_trick_shell_script/apr_2003/04212003.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused about some basic concepts, but I would guess that the difference is that the one with the `sh-4.2#` prompt is the Bourne shell (/bin/sh) logged in as root, whereas a "normal" root shell is probably the Bourne Again shell (/bin/bash). Bash's grammar is a superset of sh's, but if you're not doing much shell scripting, they're pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I have edited the question. Can you tell me if there are any major differences in the privileges that you get in using one over the other?

Comment: The privileges are identical; they're both root. Privileges depend on the user, not the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$PS1` variable is changed.  Try to do `echo $PS1` to view what you're using as a prompt.  Other than that, nothing should be different.